# How to install maven?

Tags: windows, maven, mingw

I had install maven3 on another computer without problem few days ago, but I don't understand this problem.

(I have read the http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi to install maven, follow the instructions)

My M2_HOME is : C:\maven\apache-maven-3.0.5

My JAVA_HOME is : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10

My PATH : C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\devkit;C:\devkit\ansi\x64;C:\Ruby193\include\ruby-1.9.1;%M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Each folder contain the program it should include.

But when I launch mvn --version in a new console, nothing happen. I have to kill my console because I can't do anything in it. (I waited for 3 minutes without results, just in case)
And so with all maven command.

Edit : Thanks to baba, a new info :)

The problem is only with Mingw. It works with a classical dos console.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a bigger issue at hand, but aren't you supposed to set your %M2% also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ruby to have maven. You, however, need java.
On another note, try to go to where the binary of maven is:

as in:

```
C:\maven\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin
```

then execute `mvn --version`.  Also, if it doesn't work, try manually calling mvn.bat (which should be there for a Windows installation) with --version argument. If it still doesn't work, something is wrong with your maven installation, and we can go from there.

But if it works, then it is a path issue.

Comment: Interresing result. I've got an error when I test the .bat in the folder : 
$ mvn.bat --version
./mvn.bat: line 1: @REM: command not found
./mvn.bat: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./mvn.bat: line 2: `@REM Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one'

Comment: Thanks ! It come from my shell. With the classic console, it works. (I was testing with MINGW)

Comment: Interesting. I remember successfully running maven on mingw with no much problems.